# Delphi 10.4 IDE shows hourglass spinning-wheel at start and does not react anymore

Tags: delphi, ide, freeze, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Windows 10, when I start the Delphi 10.4 IDE, an hourglass spinning-wheel stays there forever and does not go away.

[image]

The IDE does not react.

Until a few hours ago, everything worked normally.

I have tried restarting Windows several times.

I have tried removing all IDE addons.

I have even tried to start the IDE with this command-line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\bds.exe" -r foo
```

But this also freezes the IDE and the menus don't react anymore! Only the hourglass spinning wheel is not visible.

What can I do?

Comment: There is no space between -r and the registry key name. Like this: "--rfoo" (no quotes either).

Comment: First I suspected a program I installed today before this happened: Steinberg WaveLab 10 Pro, which also installs several drivers deep in the system. So I uninstalled WaveLab and rebooted Windows 10. But that doesn't seem to help. As a second try, I closed Actual Window Manager which is always running in the background, but never made any problems. But as soon I closed Actual Window Manager, the IDE start went normally without the freezing and spinning wheel. I don't understand this, I had Actual Window Manager always running in the background without problems!

Comment: Newer versions of the RAD Studio IDE use quite a lot of "dark magic", often poorly implemented, to modify the appearance of IDE windows and their title bars. I'm not surprised this causes apps like AWM to be confused.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You are right. Now I have removed the specific AWM settings for the Delphi 10.4 IDE (which always seemed to work without problems) and the Spooky went away. But I always suspected the IDE doing strange things in the background which often led to "flicker-orgies" where the IDE windows seemed to have gone MAD, often after heavily working in the IDE for several hours. Has anyone also experienced strange IDE windows behavior in Delphi 10.4?

Comment: Nothing strange outside of the flicker madness it sometimes does.

Comment: This is an issue that should be reported to EMBT as an IDE bug. There's not much anyone here can do to help resolve an issue with AWM or other external apps.

Comment: @KenWhite How could such a quality report be formulated? "IDE windows often go MAD"?

Comment: How could the term "Flickering" be professionally defined in the context of the Delphi IDE?

Comment: You'd describe it the same way you've attempted to explain it here. I'd include the information about the interactions you've observed with AWM. If you can make an effort to explain it here, you can make that same effort there in a bug report. They're the only ones that have any ability to troubleshoot and possibly fix the issues you're reporting; they have the source and the coders available.

Comment: **FLICKERING** is the big Delphi sickness. I often dream of Delphi without flickering. Then I wake up and realize that Delphi still has flickering.

Comment: @user1580348: Indeed, the RAD Studio IDE is very poorly implemented. Its GUI flickers way too much and sometimes has repaint times that make old Windows 3.1 systems seem fast. However, it is possible to use Delphi to make VCL applications that are free from flickering. In my own applications, both the ones I have made for my company and my personal projects, there is essentially no flickering at all. That's the good news: you can make apps that are better than the RAD Studio IDE itself. If that hadn't been the case, I'd abandoned Delphi by now.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Is there a book "How to make non-flickering applications"? I would buy it instantaneously! (And buy another copy as a gift for Embarcadero)

Comment: Thankfully Delphi 10.4.1 flickers a lot less for me. At least after getting everything installed - GetIt Package Manager from a UI perspective is horrible - slow loading of a large list that both locks the UI and scrolls poorly.